# Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.M4

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a java spring mvc apication. and when i add the following dependency into the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
```

it complains with:

```
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.0.M4
```

So, **what is wrong in my pom?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bellow version of dependency from current version of Spring-Beans. you can use bellow dependency :-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

after adding this update maven project

Answer (score 3):

It is a milestones (pre released) version, which is not available in Maven. If you want to use it you can add spring milestones repository to your pom.xml.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

However, since it's a pre-released version, it is not advisable to use it in production environment, unless you have a specific requirement/ feature that is only available in new version, since it may contain bugs.

Answer (score 1):

By default pom.xml has repository mentioned as below.

```
<id>central</id>
<name>Central Repository</name>
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
```

As `5.0.0.M4` is milestone version like alpha or beta version, mentioned dependency/jar is not present in maven central repository so error is produced.Add below lines in pom.xml and dependency will get downloaded.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>myrepo</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```